# How to retreive memory cache in Azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, caching, memory

I am hosting a Net core application as as Azure app service. The app uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`to set and get string values to cache. Is there a way I can see the key-values stored in my server's in-memory cache ?

Reason:- The values I set, always seem to be null when I retrieve them.
Is there anything like Redis console in azure portal to check the key values present in memory cache?

the part of code used to set and get.

```
_memoryCache.Set("key1", "value1", TimeSpan.FromHours(1))

_memoryCache.TryGetValue("key1", out string result)
```

Comment: The values are stored in your application process's memory. There is no viewer for that. You could make a page in your app that loads all values from the cache and shows them on the page. When the values were null, did the app process restart? For example if you change settings for the App Service, it'll cause a restart that wipes the in-memory cache.

Comment: Thanks @juunas. That's what I thought. I already checked and there hasn't been any restart.

Comment: Can you post the code that shows how you read & write using the cache?

Comment: Also, do you have multiple instances running? The memory cache isn't a distributed cache!

Comment: @PeterBons updated the code in question. yep I verified, its a single instance.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same MemoryCache instance, it must be a singleton

Comment: MemoryCache instance should be singleton, please make sure you have registered caching service as a singleton in ConfigureServices and you are instantiating memory cache like :  
`this._memoryCache = System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default;`

Comment: As mentioned by others,  the cache needs to be a singleton. Could you please post the part of startup.cs where you define the singleton and illustrate how you are injecting the singleton instance into the pieces of code that are using the singleton (probably in a controller constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

#### There is no function you mentioned on the azure portal.

**Follow below steps, you can retrieve the value.**

You need add `services.AddMemoryCache();` in ConfigureServices.

[image]

And you also change your `controller` like below. Then you will get the value. It will not be null.

[image]